# How to loop through the state in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a class named List and i recived some data from api and i had put it into state and i am reviving this data

```
(6) [{…}, 200, "OK", {…}, {…}, XMLHttpRequest]
0:
    0: {id: "1", name: "vivek", fname: "manohar", mobile: "8824859583", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/194_axixa_cleaner-better-code-670x335.jpg"}
    1: {id: "2", name: "anki", fname: "Sushil", mobile: "267877", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/382_axixa_Ankita.pdf"}
__proto__: Object
1: 200
2: "OK"
3: {content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", content-length: "312"}
4: {url: "http://localhost/freact/index.php", method: "post", data: FormData, headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
5: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
length: 6
```

How i can print this data in table format which i am recieving 
My code to retrieve data from api is

```
componentDidMount(){
    const sendData = new FormData();
    const thiss=this;
    sendData.append('func','list');
    sendData.append('qry','select * from student');   
    axios.post("http://localhost/freact/index.php",sendData)
    .then(
        (resp)=>{
            Object.keys(resp).forEach(function(key) {
              thiss.arr.push(resp[key]);
            });
            this.setState({data:this.arr});
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: You need only request data or all response ?

Comment: 0: {id: "1", name: "vivek", fname: "manohar", mobile: "8824859583", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/194_axixa_cleaner-better-code-670x335.jpg"}
    1: {id: "2", name: "anki", fname: "Sushil", mobile: "267877", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/382_axixa_Ankita.pdf"}
just this things

Comment: Post your code. how you are getting response from API and how you are storing it in state.

Comment: i had added my componentDidMount function please look

Comment: Why are you doing this `Object.keys(resp).forEach...`? axios gives you result directly. you can directly store data in state, `this.setState({data:resp.data});` and simply iterate this to print data.

Comment: Can you share what you get in `resp`? Do `console.log(resp)` and paste the output here.

Comment: @ravibagul91 {showData: Array(0)}showData: Array(0)length: 0__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
List.js:18

Comment: Are you getting empty array?

Comment: @ravibagul91 sorry 0: {…}, 1: {…}}0: {id: "1", name: "vivek", fname: "manohar", mobile: "8824859583", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/194_axixa_cleaner-better-code-670x335.jpg"}1: {id: "2", name: "anki", fname: "Sushil", mobile: "267877", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/382_axixa_Ankita.pdf"}__proto__: Object
i am getting this

Comment: have you tried `this.setState({data:resp.data});`?

Comment: how should i initialize my data state? as a empty array or null

Comment: @ÂnkitáSêthiã empty array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing the data in variable named `data`

You can try

```
renderTable = () => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Fname</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {this.state.data.map(rowData => (
        <tr key={rowData.id}>
          <td>{rowData.id}</td>
          <td>{rowData.name}</td>
          <td>{rowData.fname}</td>
          <td>{rowData.mobile}</td>
          <td>{rowData.photo}</td>
       </tr>
     ))}
   </tbody>
  </table>
 )
```

If you don't want to render plain text in table body and want to use a element like `<img> or <div>` you can try that too in `<td/>` like

```
<td><img src={validSource} alt="alt" /></td>
```

Call the same renderTable function in `render` method as below

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {this.renderTable()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: it's giving me 'rowDta' is not defined

Comment: @ÂnkitáSêthiã, My bad a typo, Updated the quesiton please try it

Comment: It's giving me this.state.data.map is not a function

Comment: @ÂnkitáSêthiã are you setting the data you received from server in `this.state.data` && try `console.log(this.state.data)` to check if the state is being updated or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get response only:

```
const sendData = new FormData();
sendData.append('func','list');
sendData.append('qry','select * from student');  // atencion at slq injection here
```

Fertch with `axios`:

```
const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
axios.post('http://localhost/freact/index.php',sendData,config).then(response => this.setState({ users: response.body }));
```

Fetch with `fetch`:

```
fetch('http://localhost/freact/index.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
}).then((r) => {

    const contentType = r.headers.get("content-type");
    if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {

        return r.json().then(data => ({status: r.status, body: data}));

    } else {

        return r.text().then(text => ({status: r.status, body: text}));

    }

}).then((res) => {

    if (res.status == 200) {

        // do something
        this.setState({ users: res.body })

    } else {
        // handle error
        console.warn(res.body.message)

    }

}).catch((err) =>  {

    console.log(err);

});
```

in `render`:

```
render() {

    const { users } = this.state

    return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        ....
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {
                            users.map(user => {
                                return <tr>
                                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                                    ...
                                </tr>
                            })
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
}
```

Comment: It's giving me Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/freact/index.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: in php need to add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: update to `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei, any particular reason you choose `fetch` over `axios`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 when I started writing it was not specified what to do fetch

Comment: @ravibagul91ok. now updating

Comment: Keep this answer also, someone will get help from this.

Comment: @ravibagul91 ok

Comment: use `axios` or `fetch` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve that with map
Try to write your code like this:

```
 <table>
 <thead><tr><th>title</th></tr>
  </thead><tbody>
   { this.state.mydata.map(x  => 
   <tr><td>{x.title}</td></tr>}
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Or you can start without using table to make it simpler to understand.

```
   <div>
    {this.state.yourstatename.map
    (Myanyname=> 
   <div>{Myanyname.yourfield}</  div>
    } 
    </div>
```

(For your code you should change fields,for example you dont have title field in your data)
If you want more specific hel,you should share your react code as well

I hope you get the idea and works for you

Answer (score 0):

First step will be declare a state variable as an array
state = { data : [] }

set your received data into data state

```
this.setState({
  data : response.data
```

})

Then you can access your state data like this.state.data

```
render(){
  const { data } = this.state
  return (
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Mobile</th>
         <th>Photo</th>
      </tr> 
      {data && data.map(rowData => ( 
        <tr key={rowData.id}>
          <td>{rowData.id}</td>
          <td>{rowData.name}</td>
          <td>{rowData.mobile}</td>
          <td>{rowData.photo}</td>
         </tr> 
       )} 
   </table>
  )
}
```

full example code [click here](https://gist.github.com/iammdmusa/754993070519a5c0fdd0794d770e4e41)